# How can I clear the process running on my target port?

Tags: python, bash, macos, flask

I've been following along with [this article](https://auth0.com/blog/developing-restful-apis-with-python-and-flask/), trying to create my first Flask API from scratch. I had to update my computer in the middle of my work and I don't think I successfully closed the terminal beforehand.

When I try to run my application now from the home directory of my project, in the section titled "Creating a RESTful Endpoint with Flask", I get a long stack trace ending with this:

```
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/socketserver.py", line 466, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
OSError: [Errno 48] Address already in use
```

Other similar questions which indicated this is due to another process using the port I'm trying to access. To solve this, I've used the command:

```
ps -fA | grep python
```

Which returns:

```
501 12797 12759   0 11:15PM ??         0:03.97 /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code Helper (Renderer).app/Contents/MacOS/Code Helper (Renderer) --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node /Users/nfeldman1995/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.12.0/dist/server.bundle.js --cancellationReceive=file:50e28be741e040fa2f7efc8dbdcf8a4ca200512639 --node-ipc --clientProcessId=12759
501 13126 12421   0 11:30PM ttys000    0:00.00 grep python
```

This is what I find so confusing. Other articles indicate I should see a line with the output along the lines of:

```
 502 89332 12877 0 3:40PM ttys00 0:00.15 python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

However, nothing in this output seems to be running "SimpleHTTPServer" so I don't know what process to kill. I've tried killing both of the other tasks with the command `kill <process#>` but this hasn't solved the problem.

Going to localhost:5000 (The port I'm trying to target) gives me a 404 error.

UPDATE: Here is the output for lsof -i :5000

```
COMMAND     PID         USER   FD   TYPE            DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ControlCe 13218 nfeldman1995   27u  IPv4 0xdf2d97d6ad526f5      0t0  TCP *:commplex-main (LISTEN)
ControlCe 13218 nfeldman1995   28u  IPv6 0xdf2d97d52942a1d      0t0  TCP *:commplex-main (LISTEN)
```

I tried running `kill -9 13218` and running my application again and got the same error. Running lsof, then killing the process (or so I thought), then running lsof again seems to indicate new processes keep getting created. (With different process ID numbers).

Here is my bootstrap.sh file, as requested by Jon:

```
#!/bin/sh
export FLASK_APP=./cashman/index.py
source $(pipenv --venv)/bin/activate
flask run -h 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with port 5000 on newer versions of macOS is that AirPlay uses it; that's why you see "ControlCenter" listening on the port. To get rid of it, go into System settings and turn off "AirPlay receiver" or something like that (I  can't tell exactly; I'm on a too old computer at the moment). Googling "macos port 5000" turns up several hits.

Comment: I'm like 90% sure this worked, I can see the JSON I'm expecting now at the localhost endpoint! Thanks so much this was driving me crazy

EDIT: YOU SOLVED IT! THANKS SO MUCH

Comment: After a bit of a hunt - it's in the Flask docs - https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/server/#address-already-in-use

Comment: I'm just gonna sign of with a comment that it's mildly amusing something this random and obscure could be such a pain in the butt that Flask's makers had to literally put this into their documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [lsof](https://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof) to list the processes, their PIDs and the TCP ports they are listening on with a command like this:

```
sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -P -n
```

Comment: In this case `lsof -i :5000` should be fine

Comment: The output for these commands was a bit too long to post as a comment reply so I've edited the original post. Can you see it?

Comment: @Nathan could you add to your Q how you ran Flask to start with? As it sounds like you've got it under some sort of supervisor/daemon jobby if it keeps restarting

Comment: This is my bootstrap.sh file. Is this what you're looking for? The details are in the article I linked in the beginning of the post if you want a really thorough response, in the section starting with "Virtual Environments (virtualenv)
"

Comment: Sorry, can't post code in a comment apparently. Added the code from the file to the question at the bottom.

Comment: I'm gonna try restarting my computer. Gimme a moment, seeing if that fixes things. Edit: it didn't.